# Insert quotation marks to each word in sql comma separated string and use in Function SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a string like this:

```
@Values VARCHAR(1000)
SET @Values = 'one, two, three'
```

I want to use this string in a `WHERE` clause with an `IN` operator.

For that I'm using following table valued function.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_RPT_CommaSeperated] 
    (@StringInput VARCHAR(8000), 
     @Delimiter NVARCHAR(1))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                           ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                           LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ([String])
        VALUES ('''' + @String + '''')
    END

    RETURN
END
```

This function is returning values in expected way. But still my stored procedure not giving data as expected.

In the stored procedure I'm using like this:

```
  WHERE
      TD.CaseId IN (SELECT * FROM [FN_RPT_CommaSeperated] (@Values,','))
```

Any way when I hard code the values like this in the stored procedure, it is returning the expected output.

```
WHERE
    TD.CaseId IN ('one', 'two', 'three')
```

Any ideas how to get the output using the function?

Answer (score 2):

There is already a Table Valued function comes in-built in SQL Server, since SQL Server 2016. [String_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(1000)
SET @Values = 'one, two, three'
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Values, ',');
```

You can do something like below:

```
WHERE
    TD.CaseId IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Values));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but since you now have a table, you can use something like:

```
WHERE exists
   (select * from [FN_RPT_CommaSeperated] (@Values,',') where [string]=TD.CaseId)
```

Comment: I didn't understand " where [string]=TD.CaseId" part here. why is that using?

Comment: What is here [string] ?

Comment: That is the name of a column returned by your function.

Comment: When I use that again nothing is returning. But if I use only this always returning data for all CaseId s.    WHERE exists
   (select * from [FN_RPT_CommaSeperated] (@Values,',')

Comment: I managed to get the data using ur suggestion and small change to a function.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a function little bit and WHERE clause in SP to get the expected output. That is working fine.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_RPT_CommaSeperated] 
(@StringInput VARCHAR(8000), 
 @Delimiter NVARCHAR(1))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(10)

WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                       ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                       LEN(@StringInput)))
    SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                 ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput), 0),
                                 LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

    **INSERT INTO @OutputTable ([String])
    VALUES (@String)**
END

RETURN
END
```

In the Stored Procedure changed like this.

```
WHERE 
**exists
(select * from [FN_RPT_CommaSeperated_Kiosk] (@KioskId,',') where [String] = TD.CaseId)**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to small change in your funtion

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_RPT_CommaSeperated] 
    (@StringInput VARCHAR(8000), 
     @Delimiter NVARCHAR(1))
RETURNS @OutputTable TABLE ( [String] VARCHAR(10) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @String VARCHAR(10)

    WHILE LEN(@StringInput) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @String = LEFT(@StringInput, 
                           ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput) - 1, -1),
                           LEN(@StringInput)))
        SET @StringInput = SUBSTRING(@StringInput,
                                     ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @StringInput), 0),
                                     LEN(@StringInput)) + 1, LEN(@StringInput))

        INSERT INTO @OutputTable ([String])
        VALUES ('' + @String + '')
    END

    RETURN
END
```

use `VALUES ('' + @String + '')` instead of `VALUES ('''' + @String + '''')`